# How does List<T> make IsReadOnly private when IsReadOnly is an interface member?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm creating a specialised proxy class that implements `IList<T>` and wraps an internal `List<T>` instance.

`List<T>` itself implements `IList<T>`, which declares a member **bool IsReadOnly**, but when I try to access that member from my own class, I can't because in `List<T>`, IsReadOnly is private.

So my question is; if an implementation of an interface requires all implemented members to be public, why does `List<T>` get to implement IsReadOnly as private and thus deny me access to it?

Comment: Thanks guys, all three answers were helpful :)

Comment: Great how answers. Next -- the why?  ;^)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It implements the interface member explicitly.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288461(VS.71).aspx

Note that this does not make the interface member `private`. It's still available publicly, but only if you look at the object through the interface (with casting).

Comment: This just blew my mind. *edit*: I just realized this is how we solve the "two interfaces with the same method" problem. Now I feel silly. I never thought of using explicit implementation as a form of method hiding. #dotnetisawesome

Answer (score 17):

The reason it's able to do this is that it uses explicit interface implementation.

```
bool IList<T>.IsReadOnly { get { ... } }
```

This member is still accessible, but it can only be accessed via the `IList<T>` type.

```
List<T> list = ...;
bool isReadOnly = ((IList<T>)list).IsReadOnly;
```

When implementing `IList<T>`, the type has not promised to provide an IsReadOnly value itself.  Instead it's promised to provide an IsReadOnly property when viewed as an `IList<T>`.  Whether or not it provides it on the actual class is purerly a choice of the type author.

Comment: @JaredPar: You cannot declare an access modifier on EII.

Comment: @Mehrdad, yeah I get that backwards a lot.  VB and C# have differing behavior here.

Answer (score 6):

For the case if `List<T>`, `IsReadOnly` doesn't really make sense: it's always `false`. `List` therefore implements the `ICollection<T>` (and the `IList`) interface explicitly, thus making the interface “private” for normal use. If you need to access it anyway, you can through an explicit cast to the interface:

```
bool result = ((ICollection<string>)yourStringList).IsReadOnly;
// Or equivalently using `IList`.
```